# PHP version of QueryofQuery

Tags: php, oracle, oci8

TL;DR: how can I modify the `queryOfQuery()` function below to work with an OCI8/Oracle backend?

While looking for a PHP equivalent of [CFML's query of queries](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=using_recordsets_3.html), I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2798421/1430996), which pointed me to [a function Tom Muck had written](http://www.tom-muck.com/blog/index.cfm?newsid=37):

```
function queryOfQuery($rs, // The recordset to query
  $fields = "*", // optional comma-separated list of fields to return, or * for all fields 
  $distinct = false, // optional true for distinct records
  $fieldToMatch = null, // optional database field name to match
  $valueToMatch = null) { // optional value to match in the field, as a comma-separated list

  $newRs = Array();
  $row = Array();
  $valueToMatch = explode(",",$valueToMatch);
  $matched = true;
  mysql_data_seek($rs, 0);
  if($rs) {
    while ($row_rs = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)){
      if($fields == "*") {
        if($fieldToMatch != null) {
          $matched = false;
          if(is_integer(array_search($row_rs[$fieldToMatch],$valueToMatch))){ 
            $matched = true;
          }
        }
        if($matched) $row = $row_rs;
      }else{
        $fieldsArray=explode(",",$fields);
        foreach($fields as $field) {
          if($fieldToMatch != null) {
            $matched = false;
            if(is_integer(array_search($row_rs[$fieldToMatch],$valueToMatch))){ 
              $matched = true;
            }
          }
          if($matched) $row[$field] = $row_rs[$field];
        }
      } 
      if($matched)array_push($newRs, $row);
    };
    if($distinct) {
      sort($newRs);
      for($i = count($newRs)-1; $i > 0; $i--) {
        if($newRs[$i] == $newRs[$i-1]) unset($newRs[$i]);
      }
    }
  }
  mysql_data_seek($rs, 0);
  return $newRs;
}
```

I'd like to adjust this code to accomodate our database environment (we use Oracle and OCI8--not MySQL, for which the function is written). Unfortunately, my nascent PHP skills leave me unequal to the task. Specifically, I can see that `mysql_data_seek()` and `mysql_fetch_assoc()` are likely candidates for replacement by their OCI8 counterpart. What are the equivalents to plug in? Is there anything else I need to adjust?

Comment: Found http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/9362-converting-mysql-commands-oracle-help from https://community.oracle.com/thread/2457532 and `odbc_fetch_row` but that was found in a French page (no pun intended on your last name, btw) http://www.developpez.net/forums/d540993/php/php-sgbd/php-odbc/equivalent-mysql_data_seek/ which you could use Google Translate if needed. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying the function to work with OCI is trivial, but unfortunately you lose the ability to repeatedly fetch from the resultset.

I've posted the full function below but only three lines need to be changed. I've commented out the existing lines to show where the changes are.

The calls to `mysql_data_seek()` are simply removed.  The first call resets the resultset pointer to the first record in case any fetches have already been performed.  This ensures the 'sub-query' gets all applicable records.  The second call resets the pointer again to ensure further processing after the function executes will start at the beginning of the resultset.

I looked at the [OCI8 function list](http://php.net/manual/en/book.oci8.php) but can't see any equivalent for resetting the pointer.  I think that you could use a cursor for this but I don't know PL/SQL so can't give you any help there.

To sum up, you can 'query a query' but with two caveats:

1. Any rows fetched before the function is called will not be included.
2. You cannot fetch from the resultset after the function has run.

---

```
function queryOfQuery($rs, // The recordset to query
  $fields = "*", // optional comma-separated list of fields to return, or * for all fields 
  $distinct = false, // optional true for distinct records
  $fieldToMatch = null, // optional database field name to match
  $valueToMatch = null) { // optional value to match in the field, as a comma-separated list

  $newRs = Array();
  $row = Array();
  $valueToMatch = explode(",",$valueToMatch);
  $matched = true;
  //mysql_data_seek($rs, 0);
  if($rs) {
    //while ($row_rs = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)){
    while ($row_rs = oci_fetch_assoc($rs)){
      if($fields == "*") {
        if($fieldToMatch != null) {
          $matched = false;
          if(is_integer(array_search($row_rs[$fieldToMatch],$valueToMatch))){ 
            $matched = true;
          }
        }
        if($matched) $row = $row_rs;
      }else{
        $fieldsArray=explode(",",$fields);
        foreach($fields as $field) {
          if($fieldToMatch != null) {
            $matched = false;
            if(is_integer(array_search($row_rs[$fieldToMatch],$valueToMatch))){ 
              $matched = true;
            }
          }
          if($matched) $row[$field] = $row_rs[$field];
        }
      } 
      if($matched)array_push($newRs, $row);
    };
    if($distinct) {
      sort($newRs);
      for($i = count($newRs)-1; $i > 0; $i--) {
        if($newRs[$i] == $newRs[$i-1]) unset($newRs[$i]);
      }
    }
  }
  //mysql_data_seek($rs, 0);
  return $newRs;
}
```

---

***Edit:*** I've dug a bit deeper on this and I'm of the opinion that this is misleading for CFML developers due to differences in terminology and methodology between PHP and CFML.  Tom Muck seems to have misunderstood these differences and therefore unintentionally misrepresented how his function works.

After reading through the [CFML help doc you linked](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=using_recordsets_3.html) I believe that a query in CFML *implicitly* fetches all rows into the web server memory.  This is what allows the resultset to be 'queried' again without talking to the database server.

In PHP, the developers choice of function controls this behaviour (so s/he makes an *explicit* choice).  Standard behaviour would be (simplified for brevity):

1. Open a connection to the database
2. Execute a query
3. Retrieve resultset

Typically step 3 is performed iteratively; fetching and processing one row from the database at a time (exactly as in Tom's function).  But it's also possible to fetch the entire resultset into the web server memory and then process that.  For OCI this would be [`oci_fetch_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-fetch-all.php), which returns a 2D array.  This is exactly where Tom has misunderstood PHP's behaviour.

This means that the original function doesn't provide the same functionality as described or expected by CFML developers.  To do that you would need to fetch all the data into an array and then iterate it.  In the end this comes down to developer preference and, potentially, performance optimisation.  Do you:

- Fetch and process each row, keeping memory usage low but possibly seeing slow performance due to constantly receiving from database server.
- Fetch all rows, possibly using a lot of memory but also seeing possible performance improvements by working directly from web server memory.

In the end, unless you're running a web application at very large scale I would say the performance differences are negligible.

---

***Edit 2:***

This adjusted queryOfQuery function is not tied to any particular database; it loops over a given array (`rs`), regardless of how it is generated:

```
function queryOfQuery(
    $rs, // The recordset to query
    $fields = "*", // optional comma-separated list of fields to return, or * for all fields 
    $distinct = false, // optional true for distinct records
    $fieldToMatch = null, // optional database field name to match
    $valueToMatch = null // optional unless $fieldToMatch is specified; value to match in the field, as a comma-separated list
) {

    $newRs = Array();
    $row = Array();
    $valueToMatch = explode(",",$valueToMatch);
    $matched = true;
    if($rs) {
        // $issue$ this loop over the results should be moved to lines 20 and 31

        foreach($rs AS $row_rs){
            if($fields == "*") {
                if($fieldToMatch != null) {
                    $matched = false;
                    if(is_integer(array_search($row_rs[$fieldToMatch],$valueToMatch))){ 
                        $matched = true;
                    };
                };
                if($matched) $row = $row_rs;
            }
            else {
                $fieldsArray=explode(",",$fields);
                foreach($fieldsArray as $field) {
                    if($fieldToMatch != null) {
                        $matched = false;
                        if(is_integer(array_search($row_rs[$fieldToMatch],$valueToMatch))){ 
                            $matched = true;
                        };
                    };
                    if($matched) $row[$field] = $row_rs[$field];
                };
            };
            if($matched)array_push($newRs, $row);
        };

        if($distinct) {
            sort($newRs);
            for($i = count($newRs)-1; $i > 0; $i--) {
                if($newRs[$i] == $newRs[$i-1]) unset($newRs[$i]);
            };
        };
    };
    return $newRs;
};
```

Comment: It seemed to me like $rs is just the array where PHP is storing the SQL results. If that's true, why is it necessary to use DB functions to interact with this array?

Comment: `$rs` is of type [resource](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php).  You can use `var_dump($rs)` to see the details.  `mysql_fetch_assoc()` and `oci_fetch_assoc()` provide a way to interact with the specific resource returned from their respective drivers.

Comment: I've updated my answer in an attempt to understand and explain the differences between PHP and CFML with regards to database access.  While this isn't necessarily the answer you want, I hope it gives you the information you need to address your problem.

Comment: In my case, I always return the full result set into a PHP array, from where I could reference that data multiple times. Ideally, QofQ would allow me to join arrays and perform other basic SQL-like commands (filtering, ordering) against that PHP-resident data. Such an undertaking is probably too much to ask and in any case not within the scope of my original question (it's what I should have asked for).

Comment: It should be possible to modify the function to work on an array instead of a resource.  Just change the line `while ($row_rs = oci_fetch_assoc($rs)){` to `foreach ($rs as $row_rs){` and pass the array returned from `oci_fetch_all()` (make sure to use the `OCI_FETCHSTATEMENT_BY_ROW` flag!).

Comment: sorry, had to take care of the kids yesterday. I haven't had a chance to implement, but I will follow up with an upvote and accepted answer when everything checks out. Meanwhile...

Comment: Came back to this; your suggestions were spot-on. Thanks for the assist.